# How to monitor websites and applications that are being currently used in a specific computer?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, tshark

I am interested to know what websites are being visited from a particular computer from my network and maybe also find out what online applications are being used such as online radio, weather.

I am using a Linux VM. For test purpose, I first run a https website in the VM. I open a terminal and run tcpdump/tshark to capture the network packets and saved them as text.pcap file. I have replayed/readback those data packets hoping that i would be able to see the name of the website visited (youtube.com). It seems like it is more complicated than that as i don't see the website name as destination address. What am i missing here?

Just by reading back the saved network packets I find the source address(my computer IP) and the destination address(probably the website address). However,if i copy the destination IP address into the browser, it keeps taking me back to google.com instead of youtube.com. 
Do I have to read inside the data packets to know the name of the websites?

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

DNS translate names to IP address. Once you have the IP and try to establish the connection on the destination they may load balance or have virtual hosts (map different domains on the same server) this will load different domains with the same IP address.

You have to remember that google is the owner of YouTube an since you are connecting using only IP address google does not know where you want to go GOOGLE/YouTube etc. that's why you see the google page, that might be their default.

Once you have an IP address you can do a reverse lookup and you will have a idea, but remember that an IP address can have multiple domains assigned.